# Search word to Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, search

I am inserting days in a filed like this Monday,Wednesday and searching Wednesday. How to get Wednesday word occurred rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from my_table where day_field like '%Wednesday%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i am searching Wednesday,Thursday. Both occurred rows how to get.

Comment: The easiest way to do it would be to do this: `code` Select * from my_table where day_field like '%Wednesday%'and day_field like '%Thursday%';

Comment: Please select my answer if it answers your questions! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of the number of rows with Wednesday in them and one for those with Thursday in them you could use something like this:-

```
SELECT a.InterestedDay, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Wednesday' AS InterestedDay UNION SELECT 'Thursday' AS InterestedDay
) a
INNER JOIN SomeTable b
ON FIND_IN_SET(InterestedDay, day_field) > 0
GROUP BY a.InterestedDay
```

If you just want to know a count of the number of rows which contain Wednesday AND Thursday then something like this would do it:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Wednesday', day_field) > 0
AND FIND_IN_SET('Thursday', day_field) > 0
```

Note that having comma separated fields like this is a total pain. If you can best to normalise your database design, moving the days into another table with one row per day per row on your original table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i got answer this way....Select * from my_table where day_field RLIKE 'Wednesday|Thursday';